# This code prints only the word student and not the name following it i use regex for the same

Tags: python, regex

I have used regular expression module in order to print the students name from the following text however in the code when I define my name regex it prints the word student only how do I fix it

```
import re
    list = '''Student name - Shaurya Ronak Ajmera
    Age - 7 years
    Std - 2nd
    Parents name - Ronak and Shital Ajmera
    Phone no - ******************
    Address - ***********
    Knows gujarati - can speak and understand. Reads and writes small sentences.
    Batch - 11 to 12:30 am'''
    numberRegex = re.compile(r'\d{10}')
    nameRegex = re.compile(r'(student)\.*[A-Z a-z]+',re.I)
    mo = nameRegex.findall(list)
    print(mo)
    no = numberRegex.findall(list)
    print(no)
```

Comment: re.findall gives all the values for the capture groups, you can omit the parenthesis around `(student)`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: If you want to print the student name, see https://ideone.com/KAB9D8

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly match all the names after `student name -`  and capture that part in a group instead.

You can omit A-Z and leave a-z in the character class, as `re.I` makes the match case insensitive.

```
student name - ([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KAB9D8)

Example

```
nameRegex = re.compile(r'student name - ([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*)', re.I)
```